# error while trying to select from external table

Tags: oracle, external-tables

I am getting the below error while trying to `select * from ext_poc`

> ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
>   ORA-29400: data cartridge error
>   KUP-00554: error encountered while parsing access parameters
>   KUP-01005: syntax error: found "identifier": expecting one of: "binary_double, binary_float, comma, char, date, defaultif, decimal, double, float, integer, (, no, nullif, oracle_date, oracle_number, position, raw, recnum, ), unsigned, varrawc, varchar, varraw, varcharc, zoned"
>   KUP-01008: the bad identifier was: varchar2
>   KUP-01007: at line 4 column 10
>   29913. 00000 -  "error in executing %s callout"
>   *Cause:    The execution of the specified callout caused an error.
>   *Action:   Examine the error messages take appropriate action.

Below is the `ddl` for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE "JDASTG"."EXT_POC" 
(   "ID" varchar2(100), 
"NAME"   varchar2(100), 
"DOB"    varchar2(100)
) 

ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY "SCPO_EXT_DATA"
  ACCESS PARAMETERS
  ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE    
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','    
  MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL               
  (id      varchar2(100),    
  name     varchar2(100),     
  dob      varchar2(100)                
  )        
)
  LOCATION
   ( 'xyz_aldrin.csv'
   )
);
```

PS:
This error however doesn't occur if the `varchar2(100)` is changed to `char(100)`:

```
MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL               
(id      char(100),    
name    char(100),     
dob     char(100)                
)
```

Comment: What is your question? The error message text tells you what is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

It is important to distinguish between oracle internal data types specified on the table, and the external data types specified in the access parameters for the external table (control file for sqlldr). Read the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch06.htm) again with that in mind. It should become clear. CHAR is allowed in SQL loader whereas VARCHAR2 is not